# How to show Google Admob App Open Ads only after users successfully login to the app?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, admob, ads

I've implemented Google Admob App Open Ads from here, and everything just fine.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open-ads

But I'd like to display an Ads only after the user successfully login to the app.

Because currently an Ads also appear after the Splash Activity and when the timer runs out, those Ads are also hidden by the Welcome Screen Activity, so how to prevent this?

Please help me how to achieve this. Thank you so much...

Comment: If you implemented the code as per the document you have a method named `fetchAd();` and this will notify if an ad is available and is ready to show. At here check if the firebase user id not null and show the ad